# div::before background image

Tags: html, css

I've got a div and I want to assign it a background-image and I wrote it like this and it doesn't work:

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}
.mount{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.mount::before{
  content: "";
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  background-image: url(Image\mountain.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="mount">
```

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: Check for console errors

Comment: @connexo nope. It's absolute positioned. So display: inline doesn't matter.

Comment: @connexo the pseudo element is absolutely positioned, so width and height work. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: Your URL won't resolve to anything useful from the Stack Snippet. Create a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. Use [a placeholder image generator](https://loremipsum.io/21-of-the-best-placeholder-image-generators/) to get a useful URL.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the heads up. You got any more up-to-date reference than CSS 2.1?

Comment: @connexo I just go for the 2.1 definition by default, because I know where to easily find that :-) But here’s pretty much the same thing in CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3 - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#dis-pos-flo

Comment: @connexo I think there is no change for this in the recent spec ... so the one specified in CSS2.1 is still valid

Comment: i am not sure i tried his snippet responding well

Comment: as you have used a relative path to the image, make sure that is relative **to the css file** - so where you have your css file, there should be a folder called images with that png in it.  If it is from the root of the site, then add a slash before the images

Comment: I checked my relative path and it’s true and I tried the suggested answer and the picture haven’t shown yet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose you want to get the circle shape on the background image which really wouldn't be possible when using a regular background-image directly on the DIV. To do it with a pseudo-element as you did it works:

Just add `z-index: -1;` to move the pseude-element behind its parent and maybe define the background-position and/or size (if needed):

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.mount {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.mount::before {
  content: "";
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/400x400/fa4);
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mount">
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
  <p>some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some example text. some
    example text. some example text. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is i attach image in `:before`

if image is display then check your folder name and image name

Let me know if you have a any further clearification

```css
.mount{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top:150px;
}

.mount::before{
  content: "";
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="mount">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```